# Geometric irreducibility of fiber product of geometric irreducible schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Given three geometrically irreducible normal $k$-curves, $X$, $Y$, $Z$, and two morphisms $f \colon\ X \to Z$, $g \colon\ Y \to Z$. Assume that $X \times_Z Y$ is irreducible. Does $X \times_Z Y$ is geometrically irreducible? If not, which conditions should $f$ and $g$ satisfy? I am interested in case that $f$ and $g$ are étale morphisms.

More general form of the above question: Assume $X$, $Y$, $Z$, $f$ and $g$ as above. Let $W$ be an irreducible component of $X \times_Z Y$. Does $W$ is geometrically irreducible?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome new contributor.  That is not true.  Let $k$ be $\mathbb{C}(s)$.  Let $Z$ be $\text{Spec}\ k[t,t^{-1}]$.  Let $X$ be $\text{Spec}\ k[u,t,t^{-1}]/\langle u^2-t\rangle$, and let $Y$ be $\text{Spec}\ k[v,t,t^{-1}]/\langle v^2 - st \rangle$.  Each of $f$ and $g$ is 'etale and finite of degree $2$.  If there were an irreducible component of $X\times_Z Y$ different from the union, it would be the graph of a $Z$-isomorphism between $X$ and $Y$.  These are not $Z$-isomorphic.  However, after adjoining a square root of $s$ to $k$, they become $Z$-isomorphic.

Comment: Thank you! I want to be more specific about my problem, since I looking for conditions that the proposition is correct. Assume $V$ is an affine $k$ curve with finite mophism $V \to \mathbb{A}_v^1$ and $Z$ is an affine $k$ curve with finite mophism $V \to \mathbb{A}_z^1$. Let $R$ and $S$ be rings s.t. $R = Spec(Z)$ and $S = Spec(V)$. Let $Y = Spec\left(R \otimes_k S \otimes_k k[[t]]\right)$. Then we have a morphism $Y \to Z$. Under the assumption that $Z$,$V$ and $X$ are normal and geometrically irreducible, if $W$ is an irreducible component of $X\times_Z Y$, does it geometrically irreducible?

Comment: I do not understand your comment.